# Why doesn't NetworkManager.service restart?

Tags: networking, systemd, networkmanager

I use fresh Fedora 25 Workstation.

I am practicing in network configuring and found trouble. After some time starting/stopping/restarting *NetworkManager* to test my configuration files, it (systemd) started to show when I issue:

```
systemctl status NetworkManager
```

Some not important log info:

```
Failed to start NetworkManager
NetworkManager.service: Unit entered failed state
NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
NetworkManager.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart
Stopped Netwok Manager.
NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Failed to start Network Manager.
NetworkManager.service: Unit entered failed state.
NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

"**start-limit-hit**" and "**repeated too quickly**" have some mystery in them. Extensive web searching does not give any relevant solutions.

mask/unmask of *network.service* does not help either.

`systemctl start/stop network` commands work without a hitch.

Comment: Thanks, edited typo. That was actually the output of systemctl status NetworkManager.service showing last log records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing NetworkManager is crashing when it tries to start, then it was quickly automatically being restarted, crashing many times repeatedly until it was stopped.

Check `sudo journalctl` to review the general system logs to see if there are any details there that shed light on why NetworkManager might be repeatedly crashing.

You also say that you were "testing network configuration" but didn't share what changes you made. Chances are some of the changes you recently made were related. Try restoring the files you changes to their original values and see if NetworkManager starts. Then put your changes back in one-by-one to see which change triggered this issue.

Comment: Thanks, actually it was error in configuration - semicolon at the end of key-value pair in file in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/* directory.